# Can't move camera using Ui Buttons?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am Doing a script that allows me to move the camera to an empty transform, but when I click into the button nothing happens. I've setup the button function on the inspector, so I don't get what is the problem?

Here is the code :

```
public void OnCLickButton(){
            Animator menu = myMenu.GetComponent<Animator>();
            menu.SetBool("open",!isOpen);
            Vector3 newPos = camPos.position;
            cam2.transform.Translate(newPos);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code at all? Does this function get called at all? Any errors? Please provide some more information about this. I'd suggest starting by putting a `Debug.Log` into the top of the function and see if it actually gets called.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe You're handling button the wrong way!

I never heard of the method called "OnClickButton" but firstly you have uppercase L which might lead to problems or it might got obsolete, I remember unity had some functions like this.

## BUT

If you're calling it manually, and you manually assigned it to the OnClick button event, your code actually executes however I'd anyway test it using just this piece of code to show on the console that it actually executed.

```
Debug.Log("Test button!");
```

## The fix

You didn't tell me or I missed it how you handle the button, my way of solving it would be to create gui button from new > and so on, and assign the OnClick event to this method, make sure it's public to be shown on the list.

The scripted way, to add this event to the GUI Button is here, you still have to create the button and assign it as variable to this class

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

if it gives you errors check if you have
`using UnityEngine.UI;`.